# CImage implicitly converting grayscale PNG images to 32bpp ARGB

Tags: mfc, gdi+

I am using the `ATL:CImage` class to decode png images.
But the images are getting converted to `RGBA` (4 byte per pixel) images when loaded.

```
ATL:CImage img;
img.Load((LPCTSTR)("test.png")); // 8bit grayscale
```

after a successful load the m_nBPP member is 32 (aka 4 byte) and the m_bHasAlphaChannel is true. But they should be 8 and false.

Due to the implicit conversion we need to convert the RGBA back to 8BPP manually. I am processing more than 400 images. So this is a major slow down for the application.

On Visual Studio forum I read that this is an issue in the GDI+ as its implicitly converting all grayscale PNG images to 32bpp `ARGB`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The `(LPCTSTR)`-cast is a bug. Use the `_T` or `TEXT` macro instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control, use the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx). You'll need to create a [Decoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719877.aspx) and retrieve the [image frame(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719663.aspx) you're interested in. PNG support is outlined at [PNG Format Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430028.aspx).

The following sample code opens a grayscale PNG image, and displays information about the media:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Windowscodecs.lib")
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    ::CoInitialize( NULL );
```

Create the factory COM server:

```
    IWICImagingFactory* pFactory = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
                                     NULL,
                                     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                     IID_IWICImagingFactory,
                                     (void**)&pFactory );
```

Create a decoder based on the image source:

```
    IWICBitmapDecoder* pDecoder = NULL;
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        hr = pFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename( L"test.png",
                                                  NULL,
                                                  GENERIC_READ,
                                                  WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,
                                                  &pDecoder );
    }
```

Although PNG files always contain a single image, there are image formats, that allow to store several images in a single file. In general you will have to query the frame count and iterate over all frames, decoding one after another:

```
    UINT frameCount = 0;
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        hr = pDecoder->GetFrameCount( &frameCount );
    }

    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        std::wcout << L"Framecount: " << frameCount << std::endl;

        for ( UINT frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < frameCount; ++frameIndex ) {
            std::wcout << std::endl << L"Frame " << frameIndex << L":" << std::endl;
            IWICBitmapFrameDecode* pFrame = NULL;
            hr = pDecoder->GetFrame( frameIndex, &pFrame );
```

Dump image dimensions for illustration purposes:

```
            if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                UINT width = 0, height = 0;
                hr = pFrame->GetSize( &width, &height );
                if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                    std::wcout << L"  width: " << width <<
                                  L", height: " << height << std::endl;
                }
            }
```

To verify that the image data has not been altered, dump both bpp and channel count information:

```
            if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                WICPixelFormatGUID pixelFormat = { 0 };
                pFrame->GetPixelFormat( &pixelFormat );
                if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                    // Translate pixelformat to bpp
                    IWICComponentInfo* pComponentInfo = NULL;
                    hr = pFactory->CreateComponentInfo( pixelFormat, &pComponentInfo );
                    IWICPixelFormatInfo* pPixelFormatInfo = NULL;
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                        hr = pComponentInfo->QueryInterface( &pPixelFormatInfo );
                    }

                    UINT bpp = 0;
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                        hr = pPixelFormatInfo->GetBitsPerPixel( &bpp );
                    }
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                        std::wcout << L"  bpp: " << bpp << std::endl;
                    }

                    UINT channelCount = 0;
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                        hr = pPixelFormatInfo->GetChannelCount( &channelCount );
                    }
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
                        std::wcout << L"  Channel Count: " << channelCount << std::endl;
                    }

                    // Cleanup
                    if ( pPixelFormatInfo != NULL ) { pPixelFormatInfo->Release(); }
                    if ( pComponentInfo != NULL ) { pComponentInfo->Release(); }
                }
            }
```

The remainder is resource cleanup:

```
            // Cleanup
            if ( pFrame != NULL ) { pFrame->Release(); }
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    if ( pDecoder != NULL ) { pDecoder->Release(); }
    if ( pFactory != NULL ) { pFactory->Release(); }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code against this image

[image: 8bpp grayscale image]

produces the following output:

> ```
> Framecount: 1
>
> Frame 0:
>   width: 50, height: 50
>   bpp: 8
>   Channel Count: 1
> ```

Comment: I dont know what kind of control you are talking about. I just need to load a grayscale PNG as grayscale data. My question is why when I load a grayscale PNG, its getting converted to 32bit RGB and how can I simply load grayscale PNG using CImage or can I?

Comment: @user1116700: The GDI+ decoder converts all supported PNG images to 32bpp RGBA (see [ATL::CImage::Load converts 8 bit mono implicitly to RGBA](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727121/atl-cimage-load-converts-8-bit-mono-implicitly-to-rgba)). If you want to control how the data is stored in memory after decoding, you cannot use GDI+ or `ATL::CImage`.

Comment: @user1116700: Of course you can use `ATL::CImage` to read grayscale PNGs. You just cannot control, how it is stored in memory. The 32bpp RGBA image is still the same grayscale image, just with a different representation in memory.